# How do I access a children property in parent with DQL (doctrine)?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine-orm

I have to access a property of a child entity from a parent entity to perform a filter.

This is so: I have notes that belong to a person, in turn realperson extends person, so what I have to do is to filter all the notes belonging to a person with the property first_name = "x" (this property is in realperson , Not in person).
Then: from the repository with DQL I can access only the properties of person, since it has a relation with notes, but not of real person (that extends of person). it is understood?

Person

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PersonBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
Class Person {

   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Note", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist", "remove"})                
    */
    private $notes;

}
```

Nota

```
/**
 * Note
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="note")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PersonBundle\Repository\NoteRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 */
Class Note {

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="notes", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    private $person;

}
```

Real Person

```
/**
 * RealPerson
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="realperson")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PersonBundle\Repository\RealPersonRepository")
  */
Class RealPerson extends Person {

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $first_name;

}
```

Then in the notes repository

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');

$name = $request->get('filters')['name'];

if( ! empty($name) && $name != 'undefined') {

    $query->join('n.person', 'p')
          ->join('p.realperson', 'rp')
          ->andWhere('rp.first_name LIKE ?2')
          ->setParameter('2', '%'.$name.'%');

}

$query->orderBy('n.id', 'DESC')->getQuery();
```

This throws an error, because it can not access the entity of realperson, since realperson is an extension of person.

How can I do this?

The Error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 87 near 'rp WHERE (n.deleted_at': Error: Class PersonBundle\Entity\Person has no association named realperson
```

Comment: "this throws an errror" - how about sharing the error with us?

Comment: furthermore - how about some annotations to your entities, perhaps? We can't know what your relations or column definitions are based on an pseudo-object you share with us :)

Comment: Edit the post with the error and annotations in entities.

Comment: Try with instanceof dql operator. Moreover, I think you should make a subquery, to check the name of real person